# Reading external javascript file's contents as a java string

Tags: java, java-io, r.java-file

I am having a scenario where I need to call a java method which takes in a string parameter which is Javascript code to be executed by the method.

```
executeJavaScript( String javascriptCodeToBeExecuted ) {
}
```

Right now, here is what I am doing

```
String javascriptCodeToBeExecuted  = "function example(a,b) {" + 
"number += a;" +
"alert(\'You have chosen: \' + b);" +
"}" ;
```

Since the amount of JS code is overwhelming, I would like to keep all javascript in external files and have my java program read the content as a string.

Is there a clean way of doing this ? Perhaps a library which takes care of escape sequences, etc ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in many ways, e.g. plain Java:

- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

or using Apache Commons:

- http://www.kodejava.org/examples/52.html

Escape sequences are used just to escape the string in the Java code - if you read from file, no need for them.